# Backup app data from Android 4.1.1

Tags: adb, backup

I need to backup app data (some games) from Android 4.1.1 (Xiaomi Mi2S) and than restore them on Android 9 (Xiaomi Mi9T). I have tried using `adb backup`, but current version is not compatible with Android 4.1.1 (creates 41 bytes file). When I tried using older ADB (as suggested here: [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143367/creating-a-backup-with-adb-results-in-41-byte-file)), I couldn't get `adb devices` to recognize my device.

Is there any way to backup app data without using `adb backup`? I have access to root on Android 4.1.1 but not on the new Android 9.0

Comment: Have you tried using Helium app?

Comment: @Firelord Thanks, it actually worked, I had to find APK online, as the one on Play Store won't install on Android older then 5.0, but than it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @Firelord one of you two should write up an answer :)