# `adb backup` doesn't work even with `allowBackup=true` (e.g. Chrome)

Tags: adb, backup, chrome-for-android

I noticed that for some system apps (for example Chrome, which is preinstalled by default on my device), I can't do `adb backup`. Doing so results in the 47 bytes dummy .ab file. I checked in the manifest and they have `allowBackup="true"`.

E.g. for Chrome, the content of the manifest is

```
allowBackup="true"
backupAgent="org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeBackupAgent"
extractNativeLibs="false"
fullBackupOnly="false"
```

Why is this happening? How can I backup such apps' data without root?

P.S. Helium backup doesn't show system apps.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143367 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/83080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason in `logcat` while performing a backup:

```
BackupManagerService: Package com.android.chrome is key-value.
```

By default, for `abd backup`, key-value backups are disabled:

```
"/system/bin/bu" (the command that is called on-device by adb backup) help text: 

 -keyvalue|-nokeyvalue: include apps that perform key/value backups.
     (default -nokeyvalue)
```

Therefore, you need to include the `-keyvalue` option to create a Chrome backup:

```
adb backup -keyvalue -f chrome.ab com.android.chrome
```

This creates a backup file that contains only the Chrome settings (no cache files, cookies, local data, ...)

Comment: Any way to find out before the backup failed that this parameter is needed? Or is it safe to always provide it just-in-case, and "normal" apps will still be backed up as without?