# Access my application files of an old App

Tags: applications, backup, file-system, files

I have this old-ish Android app running on my Pixel4 w/Android12 phone, the app was last updated on 2018 and it clearly uses old API or whatever and the built-in backup functions are obsolete. It offers option to export its DB to a folder but it can only access `/data/user/0/com.cooly.OilChangeSchedulePro/files` folder (yes, I'm giving out the app name)

My question is how the heck I can take that file out of my phone?
I do not have it rooted (and rooting will make it wipe, so no sense), please don't ask me to root the phone.

1. tried using adb run-as package but then the package is not debuggable.
2. tried to make the package debuggable by changing Manifest and repacking, but i cannot upgrade the app with my custom package.
3. tried `adb backup com.cooloy.OilChangeSchedulePro` and it gets an empty backup, nothing inside.

Any other way I can access that folder on my phone and copy out my DB to be restored on other phone?

Comment: Are you sure about the path `/data/user/0/com/cooly.OilChangeSchedulePro`, I would have expected `com.cooly.OilChangeSchedulePro` at the end (dot instead of slash after `com`. Also this is a strange path for a backup, as this path is never accessible by users. For `adb backup you can try to enable keyvalue option like shown i this answer for Chrome: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232796/2241

Comment: @Robert you were right, ,i fixed the path, my mistake! :) 
I will check that link you provided, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Robert oh man, I just love you, adding -f to the backup (and nothing else) DID work indeed, I was able to get the backup and then just did a adb restore to the new phone and the app db was restored!!!  Finally I was able to move that db, it was driving me crazy! 
If you want, add it as a solution and I will make sure it gets approved! :)

Comment: Then it was just a typo on your side because the `-f` option should not change anything. Most likely you had a typo in the package name and therefore the created backup files was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app does not disallow backup in it's `AndroidManifest.xml` then you should able to retrieve the data using `adb backup`.

Some older apps make use of key/value storage which is not included in backup by default. To include this data change the adb backup command to:

```
adb backup -keyvalue -f oilchangesBackup.ab com.cooly.OilChangeSchedulePro
```

Just make sure to use the correct packageName of the app because if you make a typo the backup file will be empty.

Comment: I did another try just to make sure, and believeme, the -keyvalue DOES make the difference.
Below is the proof (hard to read with no line breaks):
 `adb backup -keyvalue com.cooloy.OilChangeSchedulePro -f test1` and `adb backup com.cooloy.OilChangeSchedulePro -f test2` output two different files, one is empty and the other isnt. `4,007b test1 - 47b test2`
`

Comment: @Smoke Then in the end it was the `-keyvalue` option. I updated the answer accordingly.